# Sphinx Documentation Language, Version and Downloads links

Tags: github, python-sphinx, versioning, read-the-docs

I'm searching for syntax / extension to include Language, Version and Formats links via shortcut similar to the one at the bottom-right of Sphinx documentation page:

[image: Sphinx Documentation Version/ Language/ Formats links]

Is it an reStructuredText directive or Sphinx extension that generates these links holder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's neither. The image states, "Free documentation hosting provided by [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/)", which generates this from your reStructuredText files and Sphinx documentation project.

You can read the docs about Read the Docs for [versions](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versions.html) and [localization for languages](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/localization.html).  RTD builds HTML, PDF, and epub formats by default, but you can turn off PDF and epub in the admin under Advanced Settings for your project.